# JXTA Practical jxta II examples ....exception when NetManager.startNetwork(); is executed

Tags: p2p, jxta

I have been trying to run examples of practical jxta ii but iam getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory
```

this exception is encountered when this line is executed

```
PeerGroup TheNetPeerGroup = NetManager.startNetwork();
```

I have used jxse-2.6  to run the examples...i hve followed all the steps mentioned in the book...

Where can i find jxse-2.7.jar file ...couldnot find it...??

I am running the examples in netbeans and i have included the netty-3.1.5.GA.jar in the library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479671/getting-exception-in-simple-jxta-2-7-application).

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate, I have put a comment in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add netty in your classpath. Get it from netty.io website.

Comment: I am running the examples in netbeans and i have included the netty-3.1.5.GA.jar in the library

Comment: I'm not sure when the ChannelFactory interface was added. Please update to a recent version of netty (3.3.1.Final)